# Ubuntu update broke printer driver - now what?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

**Ubuntu 16.04LTS**

About a week ago, my printer, Canon MG-2900 series, was printing fine. The printer wasn't used at all since then, wasn't even turned on.

Yesterday tried to print, and find that the printer is 'Stopped' with this error message: Stopped - File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertogutenprint.5.2" not available: No such file or directory

I've had 2, maybe more Ubuntu 'Updates' since the last print job and it seems likely that one of the updates caused this issue. In researching this issue, it seems others have had this error message when upgrading from 10.04 to 11.04, or 14.04 to 16.04, but that's not the case here.

The more I research, the more it looks like I need a CS degree to handle this.

Does anyone have an easily understood fix for this? Or should I submit a bug report and hope someone releases a fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just reinstall the drivers?

Comment: I'm getting on up in years and I'm having trouble with installing stuff when I don't have the instructions right in front of me. I googled this, "how to install gutenprint-5.2.5.tar.bz2" and that gets me nowhere. I did download that file, and I've opened it, but how to install? That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: At some point, you or someone else installed drivers for that printer (it has no native support). The problem now is that you're looking for wrong things at all the wrong places. Why not start at the manufacturer? https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg2950.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-1196745&os=Linux%20(64-bit)&language=EN

Comment: https://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/12/07/how-to-quickstart-with-canon-mg2900-series-scanner-on-ubuntu-15-10-wily-32-64bit-linux-easy-guide/

Comment: so hi there user464: I suggest too you use the Canon drivers, so go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100626502.html and click to download and SAVE what will be cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb.tar.gz then open a terminal (control and alt and t buttons all held down together ..) then paste line by line the commands below: paste by right-clicking on the text prompt in the terminal; `cd Downloads` and `tar -zxvf cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb.tar.gz` and `cd cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb` and `./install.sh` and that runs the install script: watch for questions to answer; all should then be good

Comment: Thanks! Got much further with your helpful suggestions than I did with all that internet searching I did yesterday. BUT - got this error message: "An error occurred. A necessary package could not be found in the proper location". Any idea? Not much help from that message. Maybe I'll try moving the package to Downloads from the dir Canon where it is now.

Comment: YES! That worked! Printer is now working, Thanks, PDC! I had to move the file to 'Downloads' but once I did that, installation went OK. How the heck an average user would know to come up with that is beyond me.